# QGIS Mean coordinates, very slow?

Tags: qgis

I use Mean coordinates tool for a layer where the UID is a string and weights are real numbers. I find it very slow (literally hanging QGIS for few minutes) when processing datasets of more than few hundred points. Is there a fix or a workaround?

Comment: You could check if you have maybe invalid geometries (with v.clean from the grass toolbox for example).

Comment: @Matte The geometry (just a set of points from a CSV file) seems to be valid, though points often overlap with others (which is expected), if that matters.